# VerifyError Illegal use of nonvirtual function call on Lambda expression in Java 8

Tags: java, maven, lambda

I'm working on a project that has recently been introducing lambda expressions. One example goes like this.

```
public class ExampleItemWriter implements ItemWriter<MyItem> {
    public void write(List<? extends MyItem> list) throws RepositoryException {
        list.stream().forEach((item)->{
            if (item == null) {
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I don't believe the details inside the `forEach()` are relevant to the problem, but if they are I can post. There are a few other expressions like this throughout the code that throw the same exception.

```
java.lang.BootstrapMethodError: call site initialization exception
        at java.lang.invoke.CallSite.makeSite(CallSite.java:328)
        at java.lang.invoke.MethodHandleNatives.linkCallSite(MethodHandleNatives.java:296)
        at com.example.repository.batch.ExampleItemWriter.write(ExampleItemWriter.java:83)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor198.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
        at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
        at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.doProceed(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:133)
        at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.invoke(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:121)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy93.write(Unknown Source)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProcessor.writeItems(SimpleChunkProcessor.java:175)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProcessor.doWrite(SimpleChunkProcessor.java:151)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.FaultTolerantChunkProcessor$3.doWithRetry(FaultTolerantChunkProcessor.java:329)
        at org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate.doExecute(RetryTemplate.java:255)
        at org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate.execute(RetryTemplate.java:188)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.BatchRetryTemplate.execute(BatchRetryTemplate.java:217)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.FaultTolerantChunkProcessor.write(FaultTolerantChunkProcessor.java:422)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProcessor.process(SimpleChunkProcessor.java:199)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.ChunkOrientedTasklet.execute(ChunkOrientedTasklet.java:75)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$ChunkTransactionCallback.doInTransaction(TaskletStep.java:395)
        at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:133)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$2.doInChunkContext(TaskletStep.java:267)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.scope.context.StepContextRepeatCallback.doInIteration(StepContextRepeatCallback.java:77)
        at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.getNextResult(RepeatTemplate.java:368)
        at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.executeInternal(RepeatTemplate.java:215)
        at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.iterate(RepeatTemplate.java:144)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep.doExecute(TaskletStep.java:253)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep.execute(AbstractStep.java:195)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler.handleStep(SimpleStepHandler.java:137)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.JobFlowExecutor.executeStep(JobFlowExecutor.java:64)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.state.StepState.handle(StepState.java:60)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.resume(SimpleFlow.java:152)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.start(SimpleFlow.java:131)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.FlowJob.doExecute(FlowJob.java:135)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.execute(AbstractJob.java:301)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher$1.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:134)
        at org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:50)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:127)
        at com.example.repository.batch.RunScheduler.run(RunScheduler.java:69)
        at com.example.repository.batch.messaging.listener.SourceJobRunner.runSourceJob(SourceJobRunner.java:139)
        at com.example.repository.batch.messaging.listener.SourceJobRunner.onMessage(SourceJobRunner.java:94)
        at org.springframework.jms.listener.adapter.MessageListenerAdapter.onMessage(MessageListenerAdapter.java:214)
        at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:660)
        at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.invokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:620)
        at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doExecuteListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:591)
        at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.doReceiveAndExecute(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:308)
        at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.receiveAndExecute(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:246)
        at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.invokeListener(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1142)
        at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.executeOngoingLoop(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1134)
        at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.run(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1031)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError: (class: com/example/repository/batch/ExampleItemWriter$$Lambda$57, method: accept signature: (Ljava/lang/Object;)V) Illegal use of nonvirtual function call
        at sun.misc.Unsafe.defineAnonymousClass(Native Method)
        at java.lang.invoke.InnerClassLambdaMetafactory.spinInnerClass(InnerClassLambdaMetafactory.java:324)
        at java.lang.invoke.InnerClassLambdaMetafactory.buildCallSite(InnerClassLambdaMetafactory.java:194)
        at java.lang.invoke.LambdaMetafactory.metafactory(LambdaMetafactory.java:304)
        at java.lang.invoke.CallSite.makeSite(CallSite.java:289)
        ... 54 more
```

We have a few different environments running the same code and only some of them throw this exception. I've spent many hours on this problem and finally posting it here for ideas. The environments look like they have the same jdk 1.8.0_31 and we're using the maven-compiler-plugin 3.2.

Any tips on where we might look? I'm out of ideas. Thanks, /w

Comment: What version of spring are you using?

Comment: @henry we're using 4.1.1.RELEASE

Comment: Can you get a javap -c -v dump of the classfile, showing the bytecode for the write method, and the BootstrapMethod attribute referenced from the capture of the lambda?

Comment: @BrianGoetz I posted the dump here https://gist.github.com/wsams/b23e76cd9467144e56cf

Comment: The code snippet is for  class `ExampleItemWriter` but in the stacktrace it is reported `ExampleWriter.java:83`. Could you please clarify this.

Comment: Thanks @SubOptimal I hadn't noticed. All have been renamed `ExampleItemWriter`.

Comment: @wsams Could you please inlcude the source of `ExampleItemWriter.java:83` which has produced the posted stacktrace. Related to the `javap` output it seems to be some logging statement.

Comment: There isn't really anything interesting in this writer. I would post it but I have since moved to another team and no longer have access to the source, but I'll ask them. All I remember is any lambda expression in this jar would fail. We basically created a spring batch project and included it as a maven dependency in the main project. Lambda expressions and other Java 8 features in the project that used this maven dependency worked fine so it was compiling and using Java 8.

Comment: Unfortunately, `javap` has been run without the `-p` option, so `private` methods are missing in that dump. However, we can deduce from what is present, that the lambda expression has been compiled to a `private` instance method, which is unusual as current compilers all prefer `private static` methods for lambda expressions. But at least with recent JVMs/JREs, `private` instance methods still work flawlessly which can be proven by using similar method references. So it seems we are talking about an uncommon (or perhaps old) compiler combined with an old (or perhaps uncommon) JRE here…

Answer (score 1):

The reason could be that the interface is replaced by a version which was compiled on java 8 and rest of the code is on lower version say java 5. There is bug opened for this https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8004967

However, I don't think this is the case here since you are using java8 features in ExampleItemWriter and you have to compile it on java8. So there is no question of inconsistent targets. You can still consider rebuilding your entire project on java8.

Answer (score 1):

I copied your write method into another class, replacing MyItem by String and using a regular Exception. So, this worked fine for a list of strings.

So I assume this either has to do with your content of forEach(), or - what was mentioned above - with a version conflict.